# What's a useful recurrence relation for $(2n)!$ in terms of $n!$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, factorial, recursive-algorithms

I want to make an algorithm for $n!$ which will divide the number in half and call the algorithm again until n is so close to $0$ that a value of $1$ can be safely returned, and use the value of each $\tfrac{n}{2}!$ to compute the value of $n!$ to be returned to the previous call, and so on, without using iterated multiplication. Here is an example of what I **don't** want to use:$$\begin{align}(2n)!&=\left(\prod_{n+1}^{2n}{k}\right)n!\\&=\binom{2n}{n}(n!)^2\end{align}$$ In fact, I want something that will work on any positive number, not just integers. Is there a recurrence relation that meets my needs in this regard?

Just to be clear, I'm not asking what you think is the most efficient way, as an approximation may be, and I'm not looking for a divide-and-conquer algorithm. I simply want to find a recurrence relation to test my theory with. This question is still open; if you know such a recurrence relation, please share it.

Comment: See the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) which extends factorial to real (and complex) numbers.

Comment: @JohnHabert, I thought I was very specific. I've already seen the formula for $\Gamma(2n)$, and it's a little bit too complicated for my purposes. And I don't want to use an approximation. I want to use an algorithm to build the value.$

Comment: The reason I mention Gamma is that you want something "that will work on any positive number, not just integers." That is the Gamma function.

Comment: @JohnHabert, that problem will be solved by getting so small the number is almost $0$. $0!=1$ by definition. Then just plug each factorial into the next higher one. In theory, it should work.

Comment: Okay. So let's try $1!$ with your method. We split in half and calculate $\frac{1}{2}!$, which is $\sqrt{\pi} \approx 1.7724$. How are you going to use that to get $1!=1$?

Comment: That's where the illusive recurrence relation comes in; whatever you multiply $\sqrt{\pi}$ by would make it smaller, and besides, the value of $\Gamma(\frac12)$ is actually $(-\frac12)!$. $\frac12!=\tfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\approx.886227$.

Comment: True enough. Forgot about the shift by $1$. Why not use the integral definition of Gamma and approximate it numerically to the desired precision?

Comment: @JohnHabert, I could do that, but I'm trying to prove that the other way is possible. I know the your way is probably faster, and close enough, but could you please answer the question I did ask, instead of arguing about it?

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant " **e** lusive."

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that such a recursion exists?

Answer (score 0):

this is not a question of a recurrence relation, instead its  a question of divide and conquer technique to find the factorial, which wont be useful btw, complexity will remain same, as the numbers are eventually have to be multiplied. (This is not the same as merge sort, in merge sort one can gain advantage because of it is easier to sort already sorted lists)

Try asking it in computer programming section.

and yes, Recurrence relation will be used to find the complexity of the program, which should be

$$O(n)$$ even after using D&C.

Comment: This is more of a curiosity exercise than a really efficient solution. Frankly I want to see if it's possible, and I'm not satisfied with the existing algorithms. The way I see it, this is something that has not been tried before, and I'm willing to try it. All I need is some uncomplicated way of computing $(2n)!$ from $n!$.

Comment: Yes its possible to evaluate factorial using divide and conquer, you just need to set the condition if lower bound = upper bound then return that number, and in the function you can multiply those 2 lists. like $$f(0....[n/2]-1)*f([n/2]+1....n)$$, call this recursively. Use integer value of n/2 not real value of it. [x] represents greatest integer function here.

Comment: I'm not interested in lists. My question is essentially mathematical. I want to know a recurrence relation.